# Select anidado con una tabla

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

Tengo una tabla llamada inventario, que tiene 4 columnas, nserie_inventario, tipo_arma_inventario, marca_arma_inventario y calibre_inventario, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando en un Select seleccione el tipo de nserie en los otros 3 select's muestre el tipo_arma_inventario, calibre_inventario y marca_arma_inventario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<script>
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: 'nuevo.php'
                            })
                            .done(function(tipos_armas){
                                $('#tiposArmas').html(tipos_armas)
                            })
                            .fail(function(){
                                alert("error al cargar los nserie")
                            })
                            $('#tiposArmas').on('change', function(){
                                var nserie_inventario = $('#tiposArmas').val()
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: 'consultar.php',
                                    data: {'nserie_inventario': nserie_inventario}
                                })
                                .done(function(tipos_armas){
                                    $('#cbx_tipo_arma').html(tipos_armas)
                                })
                                .fail(function(){
                                    alert("arror al cargar los tipos de armas")
                                })
                            })
                        })
                    </script>
                        <p>
                    <label for="exampleInputFile">Número de Identificación del Arma:</label>
                    <select  id="tiposArmas" class="form-control" name="nserie"  required>
                        <option value="" style="color: grey;" selected>--Seleccione el Nserie del arma--</option>
                    <?php 
                    $consulta_registrada="SELECT nserie_inventario, tipo_arma_inventario, calibre_inventario, marca_arma_inventario FROM inventario WHERE registro_usuario_inventario = '$registrado_por2'";
                    $bd->consulta($consulta_registrada);
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    while ($fila1=$bd->mostrar_registros()) {

                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $fila1['nserie_inventario']; ?>"> <?php echo $fila1['nserie_inventario']; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                    <label for="exampleInputFile">Tipo de Arma:</label>
                    <select  class="form-control" id="tipos_armas" name="tipo_arma" title="seleccione el tipo de arma" required>
                    <?php 

                    $nserie = $_POST['nserie'];

                    $consultaserie="SELECT tipo_arma_inventario FROM inventario WHERE nserie_inventario = '$nserie' ";
                    $bd->consulta($consultaserie);

                    while($fila_consultaserie=$bd->mostrar_registros()){ ?>

                        <option value="<?php echo $fila_consultaserie['tipo_arma_inventario']; ?>"> <?php echo $fila_consultaserie['tipo_arma_inventario']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    <label for="exampleInputFile">Calibre:</label>
                    <select id='calibre' name="calibre" class="form-control" title="seleccione el tipo de calibre del arma" required>
                        <option value="<?php $fila1['calibre_inventario']; ?>" selected><?php echo $fila1['calibre_inventario']; ?></option>
                    </select>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    <label for="exampleInputFile">Marca del Arma:</label>
                    <select id='marca' name="marca_arma" class="form-control" title="seleccione el tipo de marca del arma" required>
                        <option value="<?php echo $fila1['marca_arma_inventario']; ?>" selected><?php echo $fila1['marca_arma_inventario']; ?></option>
                    </select>
                    </p>
```

esto es lo que estoy intentando, pero no me funciona.

Comment: Que quiere decir que no te funciona? no devuelve nada? no hace nada? no trae lo que vos qureres? recibis un error?

Comment: me muestra los *nserie_inventario*, pero el otro select no muestra nada, y pues como te comente, quiero que al seleccionar el nserie del arma, me traiga las partes que corresponden a ese nserie en los otros select

Comment: @gbianchi edité los alert, y me aparece error al cargar los nserie, aunque me los muestra y cada ve que selecciono un nserie, me sale error al cargar los tipo de armas.